# What does this question want from me? [Geometry]

Tags: geometry

[image]

I don't understand what it is asking me? Sorry for being quite vague, but I don't know what to make out of it.

Comment: Presumably, $AF$ refers to the length of the segment $AF$ (and likewise for the other quantities).

Comment: *Hint:* Use similarity of triangles. $\triangle AGE \simeq \triangle AFD, \triangle AEC \simeq \triangle ADB$.

Comment: This question is asking you to prove that the ratio of the lengths of the sides $AF$ and $AG$ (the lengths from the point $A$ to the points $F$ and $G$, respectively) is equivalent to the ratio of the lengths of the sides $AB$ and $AC$.  As @GrahamKemp mentioned, this involves using the properties of similar triangles.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

By similarity of $\triangle AGE \simeq \triangle AFD$, $\frac{AF}{AG}=\frac{something}{something else}$.

By similarity of $ \triangle AEC \simeq \triangle ADB$, $\frac{something}{something else}=\frac{AB}{AC}$.

Thus, $\frac{AF}{AG}=\frac{AB}{AC}$.

It's up to you to see what relevant $\frac{something}{somethingelse}$ bridges between the two shapes.